# cannot fake a managed callback from c++ (cannot cast from 'void (GenFlowcacheTests::*)(int)' to 'void(*)(int)' via static_cast)

Tags: c#, c++, c++17

I define a pointer to a managed function with:

```
typedef void(__stdcall* CounterCallback)(int count);
```

then I'll define a c++ method:

```
void CBSpline::GenFlowcache(/*few irrelevant parameters*/, CounterCallback func)
{/*instructions*/}
```

And in a unit test, I want to test `GenFlowcache` with a native function.

```
int _flowCount{};
auto Increment(int value) -> void { _flowCount = value; }

TEST_METHOD(Gen_CallbackTest)
{
    // ...
    sut.GenFlowcache(/**/, static_cast<CounterCallback>(GenFlowcacheTests::Increment));
}
```

But I cannot find a way to cast the method:

> cannot cast from 'void (GenFlowcacheTests::*)(int)' to 'void(*)(int)' via static_cast

([Compiler Error C2440](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2440)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160))

**How can I pass a native function (method, lambda etc) as `CounterCallback` ?**

It is not useful for the problem, but the managed part is as such:

```
public delegate void CounterCallback(int value);

public static class CBSplines
{
    [DllImport("CubicBSplines.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern unsafe void GenFlowcache(IntPtr p, BroxParam* broxParam, IntPtr sourceDir, IntPtr targetDir, CounterCallback counter);
}
```

Then in a managed class:

```
private CounterCallback _counter;

public unsafe void GenerateFlowcache(BroxParam parameters, string sourceDir, string targetLocalDir)
{
    if (_counter is null)
        _counter = CounterUpdated;
    if (!Directory.Exists(targetLocalDir))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetLocalDir);
    var strSrcDir = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(sourceDir);
    var strTgtDir = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(targetLocalDir);
    CBSplines.GenFlowcache(_ptr, &parameters, strSrcDir, strTgtDir, _counter);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(strSrcDir);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(strTgtDir);
}

protected void CounterUpdated(int value) => FlowcacheCounter = value;
```

And back in native:

```
#ifndef Pinvoke
#define Pinvoke extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

Pinvoke auto GenFlowcache(CBSpline* p, BroxParam* param, const wchar_t* sourceDir, const wchar_t* targetDir, CounterCallback func)
-> void { p->GenFlowcache(param, sourceDir, targetDir, func); }
```

Comment: You're not missing anything, you cannot cast a non-static class method to a function pointer.

Comment: @john I updated to a more relevant question. How can I pass a function typed void(int)?

Comment: Where is the C# in all of this? I've come here for C#, so I want C# 

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot You can pass a function or static method typed `void(int)` you can also pass a non-capturing lambda with the same signature, and that's it. You can't pass a class method however it is typed.

Comment: @xanatos I added the c# part.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot And it works? How did you demangle the C++ name of `GenFlowcache`? I've done C++ pinvoke using the `ThisCall` (just as a demo for someone who asked) but I didn't think you could do it as a `StdCall`...

Comment: @xanatos yes you can, as stdcall or Cdecl if you need too.

Comment: @xanatos The drawback is the latency involved. So if the callback can be a  "fire and forget" function, one better use some native `auto future = async(launch::async, func, arg);`

Comment: @xanatos Indeed I forgot the demangling part. Edited consequently, and corrected few mistakes in the managed part.

Comment: @john Why I can have a pointer to a instance method in c#, and I can't have it in c++ ? It's not as if it did not exist.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot You can have a pointer to an instance in C++, it's just that it's not compatible with a pointer to a function. I don't know about C#, presumably it's doing some magic behind the scenes. You could obviously do the same magic in C++ but only if your target is correct. This I think is the fundamental problem, your `CounterCallback` type is wrong for what you are trying to achieve. In pure C++ we'd use either a template or `std::function`, both of those could work with both function pointers and member pointers.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot In C# a `Delegate` (what you call a pointer to an instance method) object is composed of two parts: a pointer to the method and a "target" (aptly named `Target`) that is the instance of the object (or `null` for static methods). You can check it with `var c = new List<int>(); Action<int> a = c.Add; bool eq = c == a.Target;`

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot The two `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto` are useless. You can directly marshal .NET `string` to C/C++ `const wchar_t*` in Windows, because in .NET there is a guarantee that all the .NET `string` are NUL terminated, so they are directly interoperable in the direction .NET -> C/C++ (but not in the opposite direction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by john:

> You can pass a function or static method typed `void(int)` you can also pass a non-capturing lambda with the same signature, and that's it. You can't pass a class method however it is typed

I can pass a global function:

```
int _flowCount{};
auto Increment(int value) -> void { _flowCount = value; }
```

that will be passed in the test method:

```
sut.GenFlowcache(/**/, (CounterCallback)Increment);
```